# iPad: Show website full-screen with hidden controls, address bar and iOS status bar

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, mobile-safari

My iPad running iOS 12.0.1 is displaying a locked website to visitors.

How can I let browser full-screen, without URL bar and status bar? I couldn't find related options in Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot from the iPad?

Comment: @NimeshNeema which part do you want to see?https://imgur.com/a/MrUfV7Q  https://imgur.com/a/7xrNiwh

Answer (score 3):

Although it is possible for certain iOS apps (depending on the way they are programmed) to hide the status bar in iPhone and iPad, most of the app (barring games, video streaming apps) choose not to do so.

Safari and Chrome web browsers for iPad have no native control to take browser full screen. While scrolling through the webpage, however, the browser controls and address bar area shrinks to provide a bit more space for content.

While viewing streaming videos however, you do have an option to view it in fullscreen with browser controls hidden. While streaming video, Status bar is shown only when to tap on the screen to momentarily view playback controls.

---

## Safari for iOS

**Normal mode**

[image]

**Shrunk controls mode**

[image]

---

## Chrome for iOS

**Normal mode**

[image]

**Shrunk controls mode**

[image]

---

**Video streaming, full screen mode**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add to home screen only works with special meta tags. There are specific apps that are designed to display a locked webpage in fullscreen without special codings, like [kiosker.io](https://kiosker.io).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the "add to Home Screen" option and it will disable address bar and status bar.

Comment: This is only if the website provides the necessary meta tag to support this, which isn't usual.

Comment: That's for PWAs only.